# What's the difference between margin financing and borrowing money from someone else?

Tags: stocks, margin

Why don't investors borrowing money from banks or other institutions to buy stocks instead of buying on margin? Margin financing increases your purchasing power but so does borrowing money from institutions other than brokerage.

Answer (score 3):

When you buy securities on margin, you use your existing positions as collateral.

How much you can buy, also called buying power, depends on the type of security (stocks, bonds, options, etc.) you're buying as well as the market value of your portfolio.

As the value changes, you may be required to add additional funds to avoid liquidation of your positions.

If you borrow money from a bank or other party, it's typically an unsecured personal loan and the interest rate might be a lot higher.

Also, you're only able to make cash transactions and the securities you buy aren't marginable themselves, so you don't have as much buying power.

Finally, most options strategies beyond simple longs or covered calls/cash covered puts require a margin account, even if you don't use margin on a regular basis.